# Rspec of update request with carrierwave is not whitelisting the file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to test a request to update a `report_asset` asset, which is a file.

In the model:

```
mount_uploader :asset, ReportAssetUploader
```

Then in the rspec:

```
let(:test_picture) do 
  path = File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'fixtures', 'sample_graph.png')
  Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(path)
end

let(:params) do
 { report_asset: { orientation: 1, asset: test_picture } }
end

subject(:put_request) do
  put api_dd_report_assets_path(report_asset.id), params: params, headers: auth_headers, as: :json
end
```

My controller has:

```
def update
   # ...
  byebug
  report_asset.update(report_asset_params)
end

private 

def report_asset_params
  params.require(:report_asset).permit(:asset, :orientation)
end
```

So, the problem is that it is not updating the asset. I noticed that by the time it gets to the controller, and it whitelists the params, something weird is happening where it just cuts `asset` off:

```
(byebug) params
<ActionController::Parameters {"report_asset"=><ActionController::Parameters {"orientation"=>2, "asset"=><ActionController::Parameters {"original_filename"=>"sample_graph.png", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x007f9801b07b60>", "content_type"=>"text/plain"} permitted: false>} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"api/v1/reporting/dd/report_assets", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"820cf98d-baaf-4b98-9e4b-cbdf6c4daf36"} permitted: false>

(byebug) report_asset_params
<ActionController::Parameters {"orientation"=>2} permitted: true>
```

Does anyone know how to whitelist it correctly and allow it to update? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Turns I out I had to ditch the `as: :json` part of the subject request. Now the params are shown as `<ActionController::Parameters {"asset"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd8238a40f0 ...` which is correct.